# what is the area of the region [ (x,y):0<x , y<1 , 3/4<x+y<3/2 ]?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, area

[image]

can we do this without integration ( breaking the area into triangles & rectangles etc ) ?

Comment: [Shoelace formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shoelace_formula) might help.

Comment: Even more elementary, just take the triangles and subtract areas of appropriate triangles. After such a lovely diagram, I'm sure you can easily do it on your own. I can almost blurt out the answer looking at the diagram

Comment: @Shailesh thankyou .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note the three similar right triangles. One below the top line, another below the bottom line and one above the $y=1$

The area of the biggest right triangle is $\frac{\frac{3}2\frac32}2=\frac98$
You have to subtract the area of other two (white ones) from this one, 
The bottom one has $\frac{\frac{3}4\frac34}2=\frac9{32}$
The top one has $\frac{\frac{1}2\frac12}2=\frac1{8}$

Finally you have $\frac98-\frac{1}{8}-\frac9{32}=\frac{23}{32}$

Comment: but I have four options (A) 9/16 (B) 7/16 (C) 13/32 (D) 19/32

Comment: not sure what you asking about

Comment: bro , will you please varify diagram that i have plotted . region [ (x,y):0<x , y<1 , 3/4<x+y<3/2 ]

Comment: i don't think either of your options is correct as long as your describe the question correctly. your diagram fits the region you describe

Comment: @micheal thanks .

Comment: thanks to all . Its very nice to see helping hands . I'll study your community rules & try to put questions in better way .

Comment: since there is a bit confusion . then how to  use double integral strip to check our answer .

Comment: I would suggest to open a new question and show your effort in doing this using integration. You can link to this question if you need.