# what is the area of the region [ (x,y):0<x , y<1 , 3/4<x+y<3/2 ] do'nt use area of triangle & squares by conventional method?

Tags: calculus, integration, area

I was confused with the answer provided on [my other question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1590408/what-is-the-area-of-the-region-x-y0x-y1-3-4xy3-2/1590421#1590421)
since it doesn't fit the expected answer given in a multiple choice question:
 (A) 9/16 (B) 7/16 (C) 13/32 (D) 19/32

I would like to verify this result using integration.
I know how to integrate but concept of strip is new to me . can we solve this using only one strip ?
[image]

Comment: You can make this region by removing two triangles from a rectangle. No calculus is required to find its area.

Comment: You just asked this question today and it went on hold. What is the point in asking it again ?

Comment: You dont neccessary have to integrate, You can just find the points of intersection of different lines and then use normal geometry(area of triangles and rectangles) and find areas.

Comment: At the picture $x>1$

Comment: @Shailesh there was confusion in answer , because what I am getting is not in options acailable . so I have (want) to varify it using integral calculas .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot get away with just one integral here. The easiest way is to integrate with respect to $y$. You will have to setup two integrals.

If you integrate with respect to $x$, you will have three integrals.

That being said, This shape is simply a polygon. You could partition it into rectangles and triangles, and add up their areas. If you don't have to use calculus, I would do it this way for sure.

Answer (score 0):

Area$=\int_{0}^{1}\left(\frac{3}{2}-y\right)dy-\int_{0}^{3/4}\left(\frac{3}{4}-y\right)dy$